# How to get ordinary lowercase subcaption labels with amsart and subfig

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats, amsart, subfig

I am using the package `subfig` to insert multiple images in a single figure environment. I have noticed that when using the `amsart` document class the label of each subcaption is printed in small caps. I would like to have it ordinary lowercase. How do I achieve that?

EDIT: As a matter of fact, in the AMS Style Guide I found two pictures where the subcaption labels are printed in ordinary lowercase, and no picture in small caps (link is in the comments). So this seems unwanted behaviour.

Below is a minimal working example and a screenshot from the typeset document.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    
    \subfloat[]{\label{a}} \qquad
    \subfloat[]{\label{b}}

    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, they are in fact lowercase, only they are typeset with a "small caps" font. Apparently that is what AMS wants for its journals. So if you don't want to follow their guidelines, why are you using the `amsart` documentclass?

Comment: AMS does not require small caps font in subcaptions. In fact, their style guide (https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf) seems to suggest that the ordinary lowercase font is preferred (see pag. 46).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `caption` package uses the same font as `amsart` establishes for the label, which is small caps.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont=normalfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering

    \subfloat[]{\label{a}} \qquad
    \subfloat[]{\label{b}}

    \caption{something}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It also works if, for some reasons, you want to load `subfig` with the `caption=false` option.